# Eloquent Eager Loading with $append Attribute

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm kinda stuck with this here and don't know how to move forward with this one.

I have two Models: **user** and **child** and they are in a **Relationship**.

**( Keep in mind that this only illustrate the problem )**

```
class Child extends Model{

    protected $primaryKey = 'id_child';

    public $appends = ['is_alive'];

    public function user(){

        return $this->belongsTo('Models\User','id_user');

    }

    public function getIsAliveAttribute(){

        if (!is_null($this->lifetime_updated_at))
            return (Carbon::parse($this->lifetime_updated_at)->addMinute($this->lifetime) >= Carbon::now());
        else
            return false;
    }
}

class User extends Model{

    protected $primaryKey = 'id_user';

    public $appends = ['is_alive'];

    public function childs(){

        return $this->hasMany('Models\Child','id_user');
}

public function getIsAliveAttribute(){

    if (!is_null($this->lifetime_updated_at))
        return (Carbon::parse($this->lifetime_updated_at)->addMinute($this->lifetime) >= Carbon::now());
    else
        return false;
}
```

}

Now I want to use **Eager Loading** in the Controller to retrieve my Childs data from User.

But my User Model Object comes from an MiddleWare in my Application. So I only have the User Model Object to use and I don't want to Query the User again using "with()".

```
$user = User::where('name','DoctorWho')->first();

return user->childs()->find(3);
```

**What this operation returns:**

```
    {
        "id_child": 3,
        "name": "JayZ",
        "last_name": "Etc",
        "lifetime": 1,
        "lifetime_updated_at": null,
        "created_at": "2017-05-29 21:40:02",
        "updated_at": "2017-05-29 21:40:02",
        "active": 1   
}
```

**What I needed ( With Attribute Appended)**

```
{
    "id_child": 3,
    "name": "JayZ",
    "last_name": "Etc",
    "lifetime": 1,
    "lifetime_updated_at": null,
    "created_at": "2017-05-29 21:40:02",
    "updated_at": "2017-05-29 21:40:02",
    "active": 1,
    "is_alive": true
  }
```

Is even possible to retrieve Child Data with **Appended Attributes** using Eager Loading ?

**Notes:** This user object come from an Middleware, I must use the User Model Object to get its child's with the appended attribute.

Thanks in Advance,
LosLobos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is I was doing something wrong that is not related to Eloquent acessing the model like that does come with the appended attributes!

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing here is not eager loading. Your `childs` relationship is wrong. Should be `return $this->hasMany('Models\Child', 'id_user');` based on the model and the other relationship defined.

Here are some ways you can access the child information. These by default should respect the `$appends` property and load the field.

```
$childId = 3;

$user = User::with('childs')
    ->where('name', 'DoctorWho')
    ->first();

return $user->childs()->where('id_child', $childId)->first();

// Or

$user = User::with(['childs' => function ($query) use ($childId) {
        $query->where('id_child', $childId);
    }])
    ->where('name', 'DoctorWho')
    ->first();

return $user->childs->first();

// Or

$child = Child::whereHas('user', function ($query) {
        $query->where('name', 'DoctorWho');
    })
    ->find(3);

return $child;
```

Edit :

If you already have the user model then you can do this.

```
$child = Child::where('id_user', $user->id_user)
    ->where('id_child', 3)
    ->first();

return $child;
```

Comment: I have misspelled the relationship, I have edited the original question.

Comment: The thing is I already have an User Model Object and I can't use "with" I can only use the User model to access its childs.

Comment: @IgorMorse then you can use `load()` instead of `with()` on an existing model to lazy eager load the relationship. Also `$user->childs()->where('id_child', $childId)->first();``this will work just fine even if you haven't eager loaded the relationship. Eager loading just prevents N+1 query issue. In this case it wouldn't make any difference.